# Remove attributes that start with 'data-wf-'

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How can I remove all data attributes in the DOM that begin with the following: 'data-wf-'

Comment: easy if you use `querySelectorAll` and an elements `dataset` property

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can review the elements attributes by right click

```js
    var eleArr = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    Array.from(eleArr).forEach(function(ele) {
        Array.from(ele.attributes).forEach(function(obj) {
            if (obj.name.startsWith('data-wf-')) {
                ele.removeAttribute(obj.name);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
    <div id="user" data-wf-id="1234567890" data-wf-user="johndoe" data-wf-date>John Doe
    </div>
    <div id="use2r" data-wf-w="1234567890" data-wf-use="johndoe" data-wf-birth>John Doe
    </div>
    <div id="use3r" data-wf-i="1234567890" data-wf-ur="johndoe" data-wf-date-ofth>John Doe
    </div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Now that the question has changed :p `document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(ele => Array.from(ele.attributes).forEach(value => value.name.startsWith('data-wf-') && ele.removeAttribute(value.name)));
`

Comment: thanks for reminding.actually dataset doesn't work because i try dataset first time,and i find that it will change the attribute name.for example,attribute 'data-date-of-birth' will be 'dateOfBirth'.so i have to change  'dateOfBirth' to 'data-date-of-birth'.that is possible.but if the attribute is 'data-wf-usEr' ,dataset will change it to 'wfUser',so how can i change 'wfUser' to  'data-wf-usEr' .and dataset can't remove the attribute directly,that is really not convenient.